# Dynamics GP Table Names

Tags: sql, microsoft-dynamics-gp

Are the table names for Dynamics GP 10 the same as GP 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find out what tables are available is to use the [Microsoft Dynamics GP SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=16d5bcea-c965-4f9a-a965-f4a81b0dd564&displaylang=en), and the Resource Descriptions tool available in dynamics GP (Select Tools -> Resources -> Tables).  While the list hasn't changed much it has changed.  In addition there are addins that make changes to forms and reports that may add additional tables or views.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is: For the most part yes. [Here](http://www.box.net/shared/jc90kdsh2k) is the master list.